# How are encoded register operands in ARM assembler ?

Tags: assembly, arm

I decompiled some ARM ELF Files and read the assembler code. But, I don't see how some codes are translated to the mnemonics. For example I get a code like this:

```
#hex code | #mnemonic             | #binary
0xb480    | push {r7}             | 1011 0100 1000 0000
0xb580    | push {r7, lr}         | 1011 0101 1000 0000
0xb5f0    | push {r4,r5,r6,r7,lr} | 1011 0101 1111 0000
```

So, you can clearly see the opcode for `push` is `0xb4` or `0xb5` if pushing multiple values. But how is then the list of registers created ?

The first example is very clear, `r7` is coded by the 8th bit, which is set. But, why does the second opcode also pushes `lr`? Is there no bit flag for that ?

Comment: Are you sure that the opcode is two full bytes ? it could be only 6 / 7 bits.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are three encodings of the `PUSH` instruction in Thumb mode. The first one is 16 bits long and exists since ARMv4T (original Thumb implementation):

```
15141312|11|109|8|      7..0    |
 1 0 1 1| 0| 10|M| register_list|
```

Since `register_list` is 8 bits, it can only push registers `R0` to `R7` (and `LR`, if `M` bit is set).

In Thumb-2 (ARMv6T2, ARMv7 and later), two more encodings have been added. They are both 32 bits long:

```
1514131211|109|876|5|4|3210||151413|    12 .. 0    |
 1 1 1 0 1| 00|100|1|0|1101|| 0 M 0| register_list |
```

In this one, `register_list` is 13 bits, so it can push `R0` to `R12` and `LR`.

I won't list the third encoding, but it can push any single register.

BTW, `POP` encodings are very similar.

16-bit `POP`:

```
15141312|11|109|8|      7..0    |
 1 0 1 1| 1| 10|P| register_list|
```

Can pop `R0` to `R7` and `PC` (bit `P`).

32-bit `POP` multiple:

```
1514131211|109|876|5|4|3210||151413|    12 .. 0    |
 1 1 1 0 1| 00|010|1|0|1101|| P M 0| register_list |
```

Can pop `R0` to `R12`, `PC` (bit `P`) and `LR` (bit `M`).

Comment: Exactly where did you get this information?  Specifically about 'M'.  I'm staring right at the manual and it doesn't say anything about 'M'. I'm looking right at A6.7.50 Push for ARMv6-M.

Comment: Alright I just realized that The ARMv6-M manual doesn't actually outright say any of this information.  The ARMv4-T manual does. How are these manuals organized?  Do you need to download all of them and open them all up at once?

Comment: @mrbean I can see the instruction encoding including the M bit (8) in the ARMv6-M ISA doc (ARM DDI 0419E)

Comment: Sure 'M' is in Encoding T1; however, the document does not describe what 'M' actually is.  My point is, where does it say M=LR?  The older manuals state this.  Have a look at @reox comment in the other answer.

Comment: M is used in the description: `registers = ‘0’:M:’000000’:register_list;` -- basically it maps to R14 (LR).

Comment: Did you read ARMv4 and compare with ARMv6 to see what I'm talking about?  Put both documents side-by-side and read them.  You will see what I'm talking about.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIR, 16-bit Thumb instruction PUSH can only push the lower 8 registers (R0-R7). LR is the exception here. The different bit between the 0xB480 and 0xB580 is the push_LR_register bit of that instruction...

```
15 14 13 12 11 10 09 08 07 06 05 04 03 02 01
 1  0  1  1  0  1  0  R  L  L  L  L  L  L  L
```

Here bits labelled as L is the register_list <0-7>. The bit labelled as R is reserved for the LR register...

Comment: In my Instruction Set pdf it reads the following: "Push Multiple Registers stores a subset (or possibly all) of the general-purpose registers R0-R12 and the LR to the stack."
http://web.eecs.umich.edu/~prabal/teaching/eecs373-f10/readings/ARMv7-M_ARM.pdf
so yes, maybe is the Bit that is labled with M the `LR` Register?

Comment: @reox: Yes, in Encoding T1, M is the bit for LR register. I have seen it on an older PDF...