# Ordering of registers in PUSH and POP brackets

Tags: arm, stack, cortex-m, thumb

[ARM documentation](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/dui0552/a/the-cortex-m3-instruction-set/memory-access-instructions/push-and-pop) says the following for PUSH and POP

> PUSH stores registers on the stack, with the lowest numbered register
> using the lowest memory address and the highest numbered register
> using the highest memory address.
>
> POP loads registers from the stack, with the lowest numbered register
> using the lowest memory address and the highest numbered register
> using the highest memory address.

And a [tutorial](http://users.ece.utexas.edu/%7Evalvano/Volume1/E-Book/C17_Local.htm) I found says this

> ...the registers in the {} can be specified in any order, but the
> order in which they appear on the stack is fixed...

So according to the above explanations, the ordering of registers in one PUSH bracket doesn't matter. I.e. `PUSH {R0,R1,R2}`, `PUSH {R2,R1,R0}`, and `PUSH {R1,R2,R0}` all would result in the some ordering in the stack because *"...the lowest/highest numbered register (R0/R2) uses the lowest/highest (stack) memory address..."*.

- Does that mean if a single PUSH instruction has multiple registers in
  the bracket, the assembler automatically sorts the pushing actions
  out in the object code, where `PUSH R2` goes first into the stack to
  take the highest address, followed by `PUSH R1` and ended with `PUSH R0` taking the lowest address?
- So if I want to guarantee R2 get pushed last and popped first in a LIFO stack  (i.e.
  SP pointing R2 or for R2 to take the lowest stack address), I cannot
  do so in one PUSH bracket statement but only separately with `PUSH R0; PUSH R1; PUSH R2`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are close, you need to always get the TRM (technical reference manual for the core, [cortex-m3](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/100165/0201/?lang=en), [cortex-m0](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/ddi0432/c/?lang=en), etc) and the ARM (architectural reference manual for the architecture specified by that core [armv6-m](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/ddi0419/e/?lang=en), [armv7-m](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/ddi0403/ee/?lang=en), [armv8-m](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/ddi0553/bw/?lang=en))

```
.thumb

push {r0,r1,r2}
push {r2,r1,r0}
push {r0}
push {r1}
push {r2}

Disassembly of section .text:

00000000 <.text>:
   0:   b407        push    {r0, r1, r2}
   2:   b407        push    {r0, r1, r2}
   4:   b401        push    {r0}
   6:   b402        push    {r1}
   8:   b404        push    {r2}
```

from the ARM ARM you can see in the push instruction the lower 8 bits are a register list/mask.  So r0 is bit 0, r1 is bit 1 and so on.  So the 7 in b407 indicates the three registers r0,r1,r2.  The logic operates on machine code not assembly language, the machine code goes from bit 7 to bit 0 if set then push that register. All the assembler does is create the machine code it doesn't create extra instructions or anything like that.

If you want these in a different order then you have to write them in separate instructions in the assembly language.

> The registers are stored in sequence, the lowest-numbered register to the lowest memory address (start_address), through to the highest-numbered register to the highest memory address (end_address)

> The start_address is the value of the SP minus 4 times the number of registers to be stored.

> Subsequent addresses are formed by incrementing the previous address by four. One address is produced for each register that is specified in .

> The end_address value is four less than the original value of SP.
> The SP register is decremented by four times the numbers of registers in
> .

Comment: "So r0 is bit 0, r1 is bit 1 and so on. So the 7 in b407 indicates the three registers r0,r1,r2. The logic operates on machine code not assembly language, the machine code goes from bit 0 to bit 7 if set then push that register." which seems to imply that R0 would be pushed before R7, which (on a descending stack) means R7 is in the lowest memory.  But ARM says "PUSH stores registers on the stack, with the lowest numbered register using the lowest memory address and the highest numbered register using the highest memory address."  Can these 2 statements be reconciled?

Comment: I posted the text from an arm arm, I may have said it backward in my text.  the OP question was about changing the order of the push/pop in a single instruction.  cant, the order is dictated by logic, the registers are specified by a bit field in the instruction.

Comment: it is trivial to test to confirm understanding.

Comment: You apparently need ARMv4, ARMv5 as well.  ARMv6 leaves out a lot of important information that is only contained in ARMv4 and ARMv5.  In addition, ARMv6 actually renames some of the fields (i.e. see PUSH) and doesn't explain what they are.  The content is pretty lousy.

Answer (score 1):

- Yes
- Yes

If you look at assembled hex/binary, you'll find that `push` with same registers but different order encode to the same instruction. That will be related to instruction encoding, because it's pretty much a bitmask of registers (see [How are encoded register operands in ARM assembler ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17827805/how-are-encoded-register-operands-in-arm-assembler))